# What type of database relationship should I use?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

I found this one-to-many relationship example in the Django docs. How would I go about doing another class called Magazine. In the class magazine, it would contain many articles written by many reporters. Would I still use a many-to-one relationship, or would I need a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Can an `Article` occur in *multiple* magazines?

Comment: No an article can only appear once in a magazine, at least for my use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a **`ForeignKey` from `Article` to `Magazine`**, or a **`ManyToManyField` between `Article` and `Magazine`**. This depends on whether an article can occur in multiple magazines (frequently journalists sell the *same* article to different magazines, those are then, except for some formatting, word-by-word the same).

In case every article occurs in *one* magazine, then we thus implement it like:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

In case an article can remain *unpublished*, then you also probably have to set `null=True`, in the `ForeignKey` constructor.

In case of a `ManyToManyField`, django will *implicitly* create a table like `article_magazine` that stores mappings from `Article`s to `Magazine`s (but if you query, you will only obtain the `Magazine`s).

The relation is very probably *not* a **`OneToOneField`**. In fact a `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`. This thus means that *no* two `Article`s are published in the *same* `Magazine`. Therefore it means that every `Magazine` has either no or *exactly* one `Article` related to it.

Comment: Would I have to add a ForeignKey to the magazine class also ?

Comment: @user8686901: no, Django will create an implicit reverse relation: you can call `some_magazine.article_set.all()` to obtain the set of articles in the magazine. Furthermore by specifying a foreignkey you would link the magazine to *one* `Article`.

Comment: Yeah makes sense . I’ll try to implement it on my models , thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on what you want to do...
You have to be more specific, and tell us what your problem really is.

1. If you have n Articles in your Magazine, and each Article only occur
   in one Magazine, you have to use one-to-many.
2. If the Article can occur in multiple magazines, you have to use
   many-to-many relationship.

That's not actually a python question, by the way...

Comment: Well one for my use case , one article can only be related to one magazine. So I would use one to many like you said ,correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to your need i think you should refer to **Many-to-many relationship**.

1. In you think, an Article can be published using multiple reporter objects, and a Reporter has multiple Article objects then refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
2. If you Logic supports one reporter per article and multiple article per reporter then visit:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/.